# How to iterate efficiently row by row through a pandas dataframe while executing code in each row that looks at values in previous rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am looking for an efficient method of iterating through a dataframe and executing code that, for every row, does something depending on values in past or future rows.

I am iterating row by row (with a for loop) through a datetime indexed dataframe that may have more than 200'000 rows. Depending on the value in one of two columns (Bi and Icats), I set a value into the third column (To_set). The code that is executed in every row includes a condition that looks for a value in a previous row (in column Bi), using the current index and a timedelta.

Currently, it takes a very long time looping through the dataframe, and I was wondering if there is a faster or more elegant method available.

The dataframe that the code is looping through has three columns (Bi, Icats, to_set) - below is a slice of the df.

Note: my code has already looped through the df and set the values in the column 'To_set'. There are None values because I originally initialised the column with `None` instead of `pd.np.nan`.

```
                        Bi     Icats     To_set
2014-11-28 10:17:00    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 10:30:00    NaN  0.040220    0.04022
2014-11-28 10:32:00    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 10:35:00  0.217       NaN      0.217
2014-11-28 10:38:00  0.365       NaN      0.365
2014-11-28 10:44:00  0.227       NaN      0.227
2014-11-28 10:45:00    NaN  0.040220       None
2014-11-28 10:47:00  0.149       NaN      0.149
2014-11-28 10:50:00  0.109       NaN      0.109
2014-11-28 10:56:00    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 10:59:00  0.065       NaN      0.065
2014-11-28 11:00:00    NaN  0.063687       None
2014-11-28 11:14:00    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 11:15:00    NaN  0.047007  0.0470067
2014-11-28 11:30:00    NaN  0.041165   0.041165
2014-11-28 11:35:00    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 11:45:00    NaN  0.040600     0.0406
2014-11-28 12:00:00    NaN  0.039667  0.0396667
2014-11-28 12:15:00    NaN  0.039460    0.03946
2014-11-28 12:30:00    NaN  0.038955   0.038955
```

The code that does the looping at the moment looks like this:

Note - the column index for 'Bi' is 3, for 'Icats' its 4, and for 'To_set' is 5

```
df['New'] = pd.np.nan

for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.notnull(df.iloc[i,3]):
        # if there is a value in Bi, take it always
        df.iloc[i,5] = df.iloc[i,3]
        continue
    if pd.notnull(df.iloc[i,4]):
        # take icats value only if there was no Bi value in the 
        # past 10 mins
        # --> find the index of the last Bi value with last_valid_index() (a), 
        # and if timedelta between (a) and i > 10 mins, take Icats value
        try: 
            if df.iloc[:i,3].last_valid_index() < (df.index[i].to_pydatetime() -
                  datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)):
                # last bi value is older than startTime. 
                # Take the current icats value
                df.iloc[i,5] = df.iloc[i,4]
        except TypeError:
            df.iloc[i,5] = df.iloc[i,4]
        # have to include a try statement because until code hits the first real value
            # in bi, the if condition below throws an error
```

Is there a better or more elegant method of iterating through a dataframe row by row where one wants to access values in previous or future rows? I understand that there is something like `df.itertuples()` but I don't think that lets me look into previous rows.

Edit:

I rewrote the code in such a way that it does not need to look into previous rows, but saves all the information it needs from previous rows in variables. This runs much faster, obviously. In this way, I could probably use `df.itertuples()` to speed up the code even more.. However, my original question remains: is there a elegant way of iterating through a dataframe and using values in previous rows for conditional statements?

```
firstBiValueMet = False
for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.notnull(df.iloc[i,3]):
        # save time for future calculations
        firstBiValueMet = True
        lastTime = df.index[i].to_pydatetime()
        # if there is a value in Bi, take it always
        df.iloc[i,5] = df.iloc[i,3]
        continue
    if pd.notnull(df.iloc[i,4]) and firstBiValueMet == False:
        # in this case, take icats value anyway
        df.iloc[i,5] = df.iloc[i,4]
    if pd.notnull(df.iloc[i,4]) and firstBiValueMet == True and df.index[i] - lastTime > datetime.timedelta(minutes=10):
        # take icats value only if there was no Bi value in the 
        # past 10 mins
        df.iloc[i,5] = df.iloc[i,4]
    if i%15000 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Data in question as _text_, not pictures. No one can load data from a picture, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

How important is it to you that `None` appears in `To_set` column?

This question is hard to do in a `for` loop because the decision on what to set `To_set` to depends on previous time-related row conditions.

Here's an "outside-the-box" approach that doesn't depend on for loops. It also doesn't have the concept of `None` as a value for `To_set` and instead just keeps a running record of what the current `To_set` value is.

**DataFrame Recreation**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

timestamps = [pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:17:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:32:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:35:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:38:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:44:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:47:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:50:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:56:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 10:59:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 11:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 11:14:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 11:15:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 11:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 11:35:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 11:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 12:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 12:15:00'), pd.Timestamp('2014-11-28 12:30:00')]

data = {'Bi': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.217, 0.365, 0.22699999999999998, np.nan, 0.149, 0.109,
        np.nan, 0.065, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Dummy1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
            np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Dummy2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
            np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Dummy3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
            np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Icats': [np.nan, 0.04022, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.04022, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
           0.063687, np.nan, 0.047007, 0.041165, np.nan, 0.0406, 0.039667, 0.03946,
           0.038955000000000004],
 'To_set': ['None', 0.040219999999999999, 'None', '0.217', '0.365', '0.227',
            'None', '0.149', '0.109', 'None', '0.065', 'None', 'None',
            '0.0470067', '0.041165', 'None', '0.0406', '0.0396667', '0.03946',
            '0.038955']}

columns = ['Dummy1', 'Dummy2', 'Dummy3', 'Bi', 'Icats', 'To_set']

original_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=timestamps, columns=columns)
```

`original_df` looks like this:

```
                     Dummy1  Dummy2  Dummy3     Bi     Icats     To_set
2014-11-28 10:17:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 10:30:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.040220    0.04022
2014-11-28 10:32:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 10:35:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.217       NaN      0.217
2014-11-28 10:38:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.365       NaN      0.365
2014-11-28 10:44:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.227       NaN      0.227
2014-11-28 10:45:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.040220       None
2014-11-28 10:47:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.149       NaN      0.149
2014-11-28 10:50:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.109       NaN      0.109
2014-11-28 10:56:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 10:59:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  0.065       NaN      0.065
2014-11-28 11:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.063687       None
2014-11-28 11:14:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 11:15:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.047007  0.0470067
2014-11-28 11:30:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.041165   0.041165
2014-11-28 11:35:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN       None
2014-11-28 11:45:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.040600     0.0406
2014-11-28 12:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.039667  0.0396667
2014-11-28 12:15:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.039460    0.03946
2014-11-28 12:30:00     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN  0.038955   0.038955
```

Here's the code for the next part, then I'll explain it:

```
df = original_df.copy()
df.drop('To_set', axis=1, inplace=True)

new_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='1min')
df = df.reindex(new_index)
df['Bi'] = df['Bi'].ffill(limit=10)
df['To_set_NEW'] = df['Bi'].combine_first(df['Icats']).ffill()
compare_df = df.loc[original_df.index]
```

1. Make a copy of the original dataframe and name it `df`
2. Drop the `To_set` column from `df`
3. reindex `df` with a new index that fills in the missing time periods with a frequency of 1 minute. If your df is over a large period of time, this approach **might be terrible** :) because it will fill in a row for every minute in every day. If no memory errors, continue...
4. Forword-fill column `Bi` but limit it to 10 fills max.
5. Use `combine_first` to set either `Bi` or `Icats`. This works because if `Bi` hasn't been forward-filled 10 minutes, and `Icats` has a value, `Icats` value will be selected.
6. Compare the `compare_df` to `original_df` to evaluate if it does what you want.

You could compare the outputs with this:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'To_set': original_df['To_set'], 'To_set_NEW': compare_df['To_set_NEW']})
```

output looks like this:

```
                        To_set  To_set_NEW
2014-11-28 10:17:00       None         NaN
2014-11-28 10:30:00    0.04022    0.040220
2014-11-28 10:32:00       None    0.040220
2014-11-28 10:35:00      0.217    0.217000
2014-11-28 10:38:00      0.365    0.365000
2014-11-28 10:44:00      0.227    0.227000
2014-11-28 10:45:00       None    0.227000
2014-11-28 10:47:00      0.149    0.149000
2014-11-28 10:50:00      0.109    0.109000
2014-11-28 10:56:00       None    0.109000
2014-11-28 10:59:00      0.065    0.065000
2014-11-28 11:00:00       None    0.065000
2014-11-28 11:14:00       None    0.065000
2014-11-28 11:15:00  0.0470067    0.047007
2014-11-28 11:30:00   0.041165    0.041165
2014-11-28 11:35:00       None    0.041165
2014-11-28 11:45:00     0.0406    0.040600
2014-11-28 12:00:00  0.0396667    0.039667
2014-11-28 12:15:00    0.03946    0.039460
2014-11-28 12:30:00   0.038955    0.038955
```

**Is all this best-practice?**

Probably not but it's a different way of looking at it. `np.where(cond, what to do if true, else this)` might also be handy here. The problem is your rolling time-period constraint of 10 minutes based on the current row's timestamp. Maybe someone else has a better idea!

Comment: HI Jarad, thanks for your answer. That is an interesting approach. I do end up resampling the whole df to '2Min' frequency in a later step with ffill(), so the 1Min resampling that you do is not too different.
The `None` does not need to be in the df, sorry about the confusion. `NaN` is fine.
Also, thanks for pointing me into the direction of np.where.
I guess I'm still looking for an answer to my initial general question of how to iterate smartly through a df in a way that you can access other rows for conditional statements.